# how to fix 'int' object is not subscriptable error?

Tags: python

So I'm getting the error in the title when trying to print out a value from a sublist

```
for record in data:
    (product_id, name, price) = record

accumulator = 0
order_items = ''
if 'order_1' in form:
    print('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>' % (name[0], price[0]))
    accumulator += int(price[0])
    order_items += 'item 1 (check menu), '
```

I just want the output to be a print of those values, while adding on the the accumulator variables, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `price` is probably an `int`, not a `list` ...

Comment: you have wrong indentions.

Comment: use `print(name, price)` and `print( type(name), type(price) )` to see what you have in variables. Probably you have something different than you expect. Maybe you need to use `name, price` instead of `name[0], price[0]`

Comment: Why did you expect `price` to be a list? Something about a database schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this part:

```
for record in data:
    (product_id, name, price) = record
```

You're probably expecting `product_id`, `name` and `price` to be the "columns" corresponding to sub-collections in `data`, but that is not how it works. Instead, they just take the value of the last sub-collectiong in `data`.

You need something like this, which turns `data` into a nested collection where each sub-collection can be treated as a single column:

```
product_id, name, price = zip(*data)
```

The iterative equivalent:

```
product_id = []
name = []
price = []

for record in data:
    product_id.append(record[0])
    name.append(record[1])
    price.append(record[2])
```

The rest of your code should work fine, except for one correction I would suggest; instead of using C-style formatting, prefer f-strings (Python >= 3.6) or `format` method formatting:

```
output = f'<tr><td>{name[0]}</td><td>{price[0]}</td>' # Python >= 3.6

output = '<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td>'.format(name[0], price[0]) # others
```

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you! Oh and I wan't even aware that the f-string formatting was a thing, I'm currently taking my first cs course ever and that was the only type of formatting our professor taught us, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @EddieZheng You can, in general, click on the tick to accept an answer, which will signify that it has solved the specific problem you raised in your question.